# Depressable Button Code not working

Tags: javascript, html

I found some code on the web which I got to work...The problem arose when I tried to expand it to 3 buttons..
The Original code in bold below...I tried to follow the code to add 2 more buttons, the buttons do appear but when I click buttons 2 and 3, they effect button 1 only...Button 1 works perfectly with the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//preload images first
**img1=new Image()
img1.src="CommonFiles/ArrowBackShadow.png"
img2=new Image()
img2.src="CommonFiles/ArrowBackPress.png"**
img3=new Image()
img3.src="CommonFiles/ArrowUpShadow.png"
img4=new Image()
img4.src="CommonFiles/ArrowUpPress.png"
img5=new Image()
img5.src="CommonFiles/ArrowForwardShadow.png"
img6=new Image()
img6.src="CommonFiles/ArrowForwardPress.png"
</script>


Body....
<body>
<a href="whatever.htm" 
   onMousedown="document.images['example'].src=img2.src" 
   onMouseup="document.images['example'].src=img1.src">

<img src="CommonFiles/ArrowBackShadow.png" name="example" border=0></a>

<a href="whatever.htm" 
   onMousedown="document.images['example'].src=img4.src" 
   onMouseup="document.images['example'].src=img3.src">

<img src="CommonFiles/ArrowUpShadow.png" name="example" border=0></a>

<a href="whatever.htm" 
   onMousedown="document.images['example'].src=img6.src" 
   onMouseup="document.images['example'].src=img5.src">

 <img src="CommonFiles/ArrowForwardShadow.png" name="example" border=0></a>
</body>
```

I'm far from a webmaster...Thanks for your help...
Randall

Comment: It's a nice gesture to accept an answer that works.

Answer (score 3):

Do it with CSS.

```
.button {
  display: block;
  /* hide text: */
  font-size: 0;
  color: transparent;
}

#up {
  width: 100px; /* replace with the width / height of your image */
  height: 30px;
  background-image: CommonFiles/ArrowForwardUp.png;
}

#up:active:hover {
  background-image: CommonFiles/ArrowForwardUp.png;
}

/* Same for forward */
```

And your html:

```
<a href="whatever.htm" class="button" id="up">Up</a>
<a href="whatever.htm" class="button" id="Forward">Forward</a>
```

If all the buttons are of the same width and height, you even could move the `width` and `height` into  the `.button` section.

The pros:

- Your html code looks by far clearer
- It's easy to maintain.
- Later, you could style your buttons completely different without touching the html, but just modifying the CSS style code.
- Browsers with images disabled, blind people etc. have the text instead of the images
- No java script is required (some users have disabled it).

Comment: <a href="#" id="back" border="0"></a><a href="#" id="up" border="0"></a><a href="#" id="forward" border="0"></a> <br />

CSS

#back{

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
background: url(BackNav.png) top left no-repeat;
display: block;
float: left;
}
 
#back:hover{

background-position: bottom left;

} 

#up{

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
background: url(UpNav.png) top left no-repeat;
display: block;
float: left;
}
 
#up:hover{

background-position: bottom left;

} 

#forward{

height: 50px;
.......continue as above...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the identifiers are correct:

```
<a href="whatever.htm" 
   onMousedown="document.images['thishouldmatch1'].src=img4.src" 
   onMouseup="document.images['thishouldmatch1'].src=img3.src">

<img src="CommonFiles/ArrowUpShadow.png" name="thishouldmatch1" border=0></a>
```